# What is the purpose of the large resistance from gate to drainin this MOSFET circuit?

Tags: mosfet

In the circuit below, what is the purpose of the very large resistance (\$5 M \Omega\$) between the MOSFET gate and drain terminals?

[image: MOSFET circuit]

I have seen circuits before which have a connection between the gate and the drain of the device called enhancement mode devices which can act as non-linear resistors. Is the circuit above related in anyway?

Comment: Without this resistor, the circuit will not work as an amplifier because Vin = Vgs = Vds. But with this feedback resistor in place, Vin is no longer equal to Vds.

Comment: Actually, without \$R_G\$ the voltage at the gate of the MOSFET is **undefined** as it will be isolated. Any charge that is trapped there cannot escape (assuming the coupling capacitor and the MOSFET's gate have no leakage). This must be solved by using a resistor to some DC voltage, here it is the voltage on the drain so that the MOSFET is **biased** at a certain current so that it can work as a signal amplifier.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a bias resistor. The drain voltage will fall to VGSth, assuming zero gate current, and therefore zero voltage across R<sub>G</sub>.

The FET is now biassed into the linear amplifier region.